# How Can I implement functions like mean.median and variance if I have a dictionary with 2 keys in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have many files in a folder that like this one:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MitYd.png)

and I'm trying to implement a dictionary for data. I'm interested in create it with 2 keys (the first one is the http address and the second is the third field (plugin used), like adblock). The values are referred to different metrics so my intention is to compute the for each site and plugin the mean,median and variance of each metric, once the dictionary has been implemented. For example for the mean, my intention is to consider all the 4-th field values in the file, etc. I tried to write this code but, first of all, I'm not sure that it is correct.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kjrqx.png)

I read others posts but no-one solved my problem, since they threats or only one key or they don't show how to access the different values inside the dictionary to compute the mean,median and variance.
The problem is simple, admitting that the dictionary implementation is ok, in which way must I access the different values for the key1:www.google.it -> key2:adblock ?
Any kind oh help is accepted and I'm available for any other answer.

Comment: please post your code as text rather than an image :( [here's](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) the editing help page if that's what you need

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want using a dictionary, but you should really consider using the [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) library. This library is centered around tabular data structure called "DataFrame" that excels in column-wise and row-wise calculations such as the one that you seem to need.

To get you started, here is the Pandas code that reads *one* text file using the [read_fwf()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html#pandas.read_fwf) method. It also displays the mean and variance for the fourth column:

```py
# import the Pandas library:
import pandas as pd

# Read the file 'table.txt' into a DataFrame object. Assume
# a header-less, fixed-width file like in your example:
df = pd.read_fwf("table.txt", header=None)

# Show the content of the DataFrame object:
print(df)

# Print the fourth column (zero-indexed):
print(df[3])

# Print the mean for the fourth column:
print(df[3].mean())

# Print the variance for the fourth column:
print(df[3].var())
```

There are [different ways of selecting columns and rows](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) from a DataFrame object. The square brackets `[ ]` in the previous examples selected a column in the data frame by column number. If you want to calculate the mean of the fourth column only from those rows that contain `adblock` in the third column, you can do it like so:

```py
# Print those rows from the data frame that have the value 'adblock'
# in the third column (zero-indexed):
print(df[df[2] == "adblock"])

# Print only the fourth column (zero-indexed) from that data frame:
print(df[df[2] == "adblock"][3])

# Print the mean of the fourth column from that data frame:
print(df[df[2] == "adblock"][3].mean())
```

**EDIT:**
You can also calculate the mean or variance for more than one column at the same time:

```py
# Use a list of column numbers to calculate the mean for all of them
# at the same time:

l = [3, 4, 5]
print(df[l].mean())
```

**END EDIT**

If you want to read the data from several files and do the calculations for the concatenated data, you can use the [concat()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat) method. This method takes a list of DataFrame objects and concatenates them (by default, row-wise). Use the following line to create a DataFrame from all `*.txt` files in your directory:

```py
df = pd.concat([pd.read_fwf(file, header=None) for file in glob.glob("*.txt")],
               ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer. It works, I test it for one file. I asked this answer in order to know how do a dictionary, because even if your solution works (and mine with numpy too), the problem is that in output I got one file for each site and plugin with the results (mean, median and variance) for each column in the file, starting from the fourth column. @Schmuddi
but that person told me that manage all these files after, with matplotlib, could be difficult or long, so He told me: build a dictionary to avoid this and manage data more quickly and easily.

Comment: My goal is not use the concat method, since then I want only to compare the obtained results for the same site but different plugins.

Comment: @AndersonSilva: In my experience, Pandas data frames usually perform much better than corresponding dictionaries, *especially* if you want to do calculations on the columns. I very often work with data frames with more than 15,000,000 rows, and there is nothing difficult or slow about that. Plus, Matplotlib (and in particular, Seaborn which builds on top of it) work very nicely with data frames. For me, the switch from dictionaries to DataFrames was a dramatic improvement, but of course, your mileage may vary.

Comment: I've added another example if you're interested in calculating the mean for more than one column at the same time, as your comment suggests that this is one of your concerns.

Comment: I understood, but my questions is: also in this case will I have different files in output, i.e. one file for each website-plugin? Because I have a file for each website-plugin, so it is obvious think that I will obtain results in each file (like in my case, when I tried to solve it with numpy and it works)..Just to know how to manage (and plot) the results, as second step, after this operation.
Thanks for you help, that is very precious for me.